# Changing background colour of a layer in cocos2d js

Tags: background-color, cocos2d-js

I am building an android app.....
I tried using `cc.color(,,)` but isnt working as expected...
Could someone tell me how to change the layer background colour??
Thanks.

```
var GameScene = cc.Scene.extend({
onEnter:function () {
    this._super();
    var layer = new GameLayer();
    this.addChild(layer);

    backgroundLayer = new cc.LayerColor.create();
    backgroundLayer.changeWidthAndHeight(winSize.width, winSize.height);
    backgroundLayer.setColor(cc.c3b(144, 192, 248));
    layer.addChild(backgroundLayer);
    backgroundLayer.setPosition(cc.p(winSize.width * 0.5, winSize.height *       0.5));


}
});
```

Comment: What cocos2d-js version are you using? Are you getting no errors in the console when you run that code?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to add a new layer/node to change the background color of a layer. You can simply change the background color of the GameLayer itself by extending LayerColor and calling the appropriate super constructor from within the init function:

```
var GameLayer = cc.LayerColor.extend({
    init:function () {
        this._super(cc.color.WHITE);
        //...
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you mean to pass cc.color.WHITE to super in the ctor function no init?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to create LayerColor and add it to the scene as a background to color it. The controller/rootNode layer is only Layer, not LayerColor and you can't set the specific one.

```
backgroundLayer = new cc.LayerColor.create();
backgroundLayer.changeWidthAndHeight(winSize.width, winSize.height);
backgroundLayer.setColor(cc.c3b(144, 192, 248));
controller.addChild(backgroundLayer);
backgroundLayer.setPosition(cc.p(winSize.width * 0.5, winSize.height * 0.5));
```

Comment: I have used this code and there is no change in the background colour...I have edited the question,the way am using it..is that correct? @sortris

Comment: change line:

cc.addChild(backgroundLayer);

to 

layer.addChild(backgroundLayer);

Comment: I am using v3.3 @ Sebastián Vansteenkiste .... i made the change but still there is no change in layer colour.. @ sortris

Comment: I have fixed that issue....Could you help me out with this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29193210/setting-ui-button-width-and-height-in-cocos2d-js-android-application @ sortris

Comment: If you fixed that issue please post how you did it. For the next ones :)

Comment: I started drawing a rectangle with required colour as background instead of changing layer colour....Can we share game score through whatsapp,facebook,twitter or any social sharing options in cocos2d js??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29183011/social-sharing-with-cocos2d-js-android-application @ sortris