# Social Sharing with Cocos2d js android application

Tags: android, cocos2d-js, socialshare

Hi i am building an android game using cocos2d js v3...

I want to share the users high score to whatsapp,facebook,twitter,through email or any such sharing options...

Is there any plugin available for the same and how to implement it...

Any help regarding this would be greatful.
Thanks.

Comment: This should get you started: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Facebook

Comment: I will try that...But what about other sharing options such as WhatsApp twitter email hike or any such installed application?? @ Sebastián Vansteenkiste

Comment: The links to setup Facebook integration in the page u provided do not exist!..How do I proceed??? @ Sebastián Vansteenkiste

Comment: Whoops! Sorry. The Facebook API docs seem to have moved here: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Facebook_API_References_in_JavaScript . As to how to share with other apps.. I'm not really sure, sorry. I can at least say that for twitter it's as easy as opening a link in JS, like this: `window.open('http://twitter.com/home?status=' +encodeURIComponent('Your default tweet text @someone #something here'),'_blank');`