# Setting UI Button width and height in cocos2d js android application

Tags: uibutton, cocos2d-js

In my Cocos2d js android app i have a UI button as

```
    var button=new ccui.Button();
    button.loadTextures(res.play_png,res.play_png);
    button.setAnchorPoint(cc.p(0,0));
    button.x=size.width/2;
    button.y=size.height/2;
    this.addChild(button);
```

The button loads and i am able to set it at any position on the screen.

But i am unable to change its width and height to specified number of pixels.
I want something like

```
button.width=100;
button.height=100;
```

I did not find any method to do that...

Any help how to accomplish this would be greatful.

Thanks.

The buttons i use are options like play,how to play,share etc..

So i have to position them in such a way that they dont overlap or get distorted for various screen resolutions...

How can i use the setScale method in this context???

Comment: What about .setScale method? As far as I know, you can't change sprite's width and height by modifying its attribute.

Comment: I have edited the question...You can get now a better understanding of my issue...The setScale method will distort the image for larger values right! @ sortris

Comment: An alternative could be creating a Scale9Sprite and putting your button's text on top of it, then handling the touch events manually rather than relying in a button.

Comment: Could u provide some sample code for doing that            @ Sebastián Vansteenkiste

Answer (score 2):

We can make a call to a function that can scale the size of the UIButton by performing an action. In this case, the following code might help:

```
 performScaleAction : function() 
 {
    var duration = 0;   // duration in seconds for performing this action
    var scaleX = 0.5;   // scale factor for X-axis
    var scaleY = 0.5;   // scale factor for Y-axis
    var scaleAction = new cc.ScaleTo(duration , scaleX , scaleY );
    this.runAction(scaleAction);
 }
```

Now, call the above function in the following way:

```
this.performScaleAction();
this.addChild(button);
```

So, if the actual height of the image used for creating the UIButton is h, in this case, the new size as displayed on the screen would be h times scaleX . Same for the width of the UIButton.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Now if i have two buttons beside each other seperated by 5 px...On larger resolution phones wouldnt the first button overlap the second???

Comment: yeah but scaleX scaleY and h and w of the image are constant values..how the button size would change according to screen resolution??? @ New Guy